# Force ionic to use latest chrome engine?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing an Ionic 3 application. The problem is that, when I run the application natively by `ionic cordova run android` it runs in WebView 37.0.0 which seems pretty old to me. Can I somehow force ionic to run in the best available engine?

For example, if I run it in the browser on the same device, app is served through chrome V 58.
[image]

Thanks!